# htaccess Rewrite subdirectory to php page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've successfully rewritten

```
RewriteRule ^alphabetical alpha.php
```

So that when anyone comes to www.example.com/alphabetical it loads alpha.php. However, I'm having problems creating a rule so that when someone comes to www.example.com/alphabetical/a it should loa alpha-a.php. This is the rule I've tried that isn't working:

```
RewriteRule ^alphabetical/a alpha-a.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your second more specific rule on top of the the first rule. 
RewriteRule ^alphabetical/a alpha-a.php 
RewriteRule ^alphabetical alpha.php

further, you can use a $ at the end to denote an end of url, saying urls ending with 'a'.